# Need to create third table based on ID range in first table and line items in second table

Tags: sql

The first table contains a range of account IDs for a company.

Table 1 Company

```
CID Minacct Maxacct
1 100 200
2 300 350
3 500 700
```

The second table contains line items for balances in accounts.  The key to this problem, is that not all accounts are used in an account range from table 1.  For ex., Company 1 could have account IDs from 100 to 200, but in actuality only has 100, 105, 118, and 170.

Table 2 Accts

```
AcctID Balance
100 $5
105 $10
118 $15
170 $20
300 $25
325 $30
350 $35
501 $40
502 $45
503 $50
602 $55
700 $60
```

Need to create Table 3 that combines Tables 1 and 2, hopefully using a nifty Select and not a slow loop.

```
CID AcctID Bal
1 100 $5
1 105 $10
1 118 $15
1 170 $20
2 300 $25
2 325 $30
2 350 $35
3 501 $40
3 502 $45
3 503 $50
3 602 $55
3 700 $60
```

Thanks!!

David

Answer (score 0):

This is a `join` query but the join condition is an inequality:

```
select c.cid, a.*
from accts a join
     company c
     on a.acctid between c.minacct and c.maxacct;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that was perfect.  Didn't think you could join on a range.  And thanks for helping format the tables. -- David

Comment: @DavidWhitehouse . . . This is called a "non-equijoin" (none of the join keys have an equality condition).  They are typically less efficient than equijoins, but you don't need to worry unless your `company` table has thousands of rows.